# Convert UTC datetime column into IST datatime

Tags: python-3.x

I have df(.xlsx format) with date column in UTC format

```
date
2018-07-31 00:00
2018-07-31 00:10    
2018-07-31 00:20    
2018-07-31 00:30    
2018-07-31 00:40
```

i would like convert into IST(+5:30) format like below

```
date
2018-07-31 05:30
2018-07-31 05:40    
2018-07-31 05:50    
2018-07-31 06:00    
2018-07-31 06:10

many solutions available on stack overflow but its does not match with my criteria.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one approach using `datetime.timedelta`.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
data = ["2018-07-31 00:00", "2018-07-31 00:10", "2018-07-31 00:20", "2018-07-31 00:30", "2018-07-31 00:40"]
for i in data:
    print( datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") + datetime.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30) )
```

**Output:**

```
2018-07-31 05:30:00
2018-07-31 05:40:00
2018-07-31 05:50:00
2018-07-31 06:00:00
2018-07-31 06:10:00
```

---

Using `pytz` module.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone, utc

tz = timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
data = ["2018-07-31 00:00", "2018-07-31 00:10", "2018-07-31 00:20", "2018-07-31 00:30", "2018-07-31 00:40"]
for i in data:
    print( datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").replace(tzinfo=utc).astimezone(tz) )
```

**Output:**

```
2018-07-31 05:30:00+05:30
2018-07-31 05:40:00+05:30
2018-07-31 05:50:00+05:30
2018-07-31 06:00:00+05:30
2018-07-31 06:10:00+05:30
```

---

Pandas DF

```
import pandas as pd

data = ["2018-07-31 00:00", "2018-07-31 00:10", "2018-07-31 00:20", "2018-07-31 00:30", "2018-07-31 00:40"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": data})
df["Date_IST"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]) + pd.DateOffset(hours=5, minutes=30)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
               Date            Date_IST
0  2018-07-31 00:00 2018-07-31 05:30:00
1  2018-07-31 00:10 2018-07-31 05:40:00
2  2018-07-31 00:20 2018-07-31 05:50:00
3  2018-07-31 00:30 2018-07-31 06:00:00
4  2018-07-31 00:40 2018-07-31 06:10:00
```

Comment: thanx for your support

Comment: Are you getting a pandas DF?